# Std::nth_element is not giving the correct element

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, median

I don't know why in this case the function std::nth_element is not giving me the correct median for the X axis.

For this test I created a vector of point: `std::vector<Point> points = {Point {70, 70}, Point {50, 30}, Point {35, 45}};`

The function call is:

```
int median = (start + end) / 2;
Point split = get(points.begin() + start, points.begin() + median, points.begin() + end);
```

Where `start = 0; end = 2;` In my mind the correct median for the X axis is `Point(50, 30)`, instead this code gives me `Point(70, 70)`.

Below there is the code for finding the median:

```
template <typename Iterator>
    Point get(Iterator start, Iterator median, Iterator end) 
    {
        std::nth_element(
            start, 
            median, 
            end,
            [](const Point &point1, const Point &point2) { 
                return point1.getX() < point2.getX(); 
            }
        );
    
        std::vector<Point>::iterator iter = median;
        std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
        return *iter;
    }
```

Comment: A variable named `median` and a function called `median`? How does that work? Please take some time to learn how to create a [mre] to show us, preferably something which we can copy and build and debug ourselves.

Comment: My bad I copied my code and I changed the name on stack. I didn't realise it.

Comment: Your function `get` does not return the median element but the one pointed by `end` (after partition).

Comment: I've just changed. I copied in a wrong way because I was testing. If I return the median is giving me `Point(70, 70)`. I just edited the code in a correct way

Comment: Works for me: https://godbolt.org/z/GExTTdYef please provide [mcve] to backup your claims. Most probably you are using `get` in wrong way.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/4Ghhrz7GW

Comment: I performed the test with my case: https://godbolt.org/z/s48nox54G It is working since I didn't understand that nth_element gets a range [start, end) by excluding the end.

Comment: All functions working with iterators should "exclude" the end iterator. Remember that the end iterator is always one beyond the last element of the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `end` is not correctly pointing to the end of the vector. Hence, you only perform `nth_element()` on the first 2 elements. Since the variable `median` value is 1, the point with greater x value will be returned.

You can use `points.end()` instead of `points.begin() + end`.

Comment: No because I'm working on range of vector so I can not use `points.end()`. It should be correct to use `points.begin() + end`

Comment: Ok, if you want to perform the function on 2 elements only then that is correct. If 3 are needed, then it should be `points.begin() + end + 1` at least, since [nth_element()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) is working on elements the range [first, last), excluding element pointed to by `last`

Comment: You are right nth_element is getting the range [first, last). By adding 1 to the end it work.

Answer (score 0):

If you carefully read the description of the function in the CPP reference [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element), then you will see:

> nth_element is a partial sorting algorithm that rearranges elements in [first, last) such that: The element pointed at by nth is changed to whatever element would occur in that position if [first, last) were sorted.

Important for your problem is `[first, last)` which denotes a half open range.

And per definition a half-open range is one which includes the first element, but **NOT** the last one. The last is not included. If you want to include it, you need to go one step further. In your case: last+1.

So, you simply call the function with a wrong parameter. No issue.

The correct code could be something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

struct Point {
    int x{};
    int y{};
    int getX() const { return x; }
    int getY() const { return y; }

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Point& p) {
        return os << p.x << ' ' << p.y;
    }
};

template <typename Iterator>
Point get(Iterator start, Iterator median, Iterator end)
{
    std::nth_element(
        start,
        median,
        end,
        [](const Point& point1, const Point& point2) {
            return point1.getX() < point2.getX();
        }
    );

    std::vector<Point>::iterator iter = median;
    return *iter;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<Point> points = { Point {70, 70}, Point {50, 30}, Point {35, 45} };

    int start = 0, end = 2;
    int median = (start + end) / 2;
    Point split = get(points.begin() + start, points.begin() + median, points.begin()+end+1);
    std::cout << split << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Yes the problem was that the end is excluded.